# Using forge.tabs can I hide the close button?

Tags: tabs, trigger.io

I want to simply wrap an HTML5 web app. Can I hide the close button or the entire heading?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using the tabs module you can load the external page directly in the main webview. You can do this with javascript using code like:

```
window.location = 'http://example.com/mobile-site';
```

However, by default external pages will be opened in the devices browser, to allow external sites you need to add them to the list of trusted urls in the app config. Trusted urls are match patterns as described here: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns.html